# Python interactive console using curses lib getstr() function dosen't wait for user input

Tags: python, input, console, curses, python-curses

I'm trying to do an interactive console using the [curses](https://docs.python.org/3/library/curses.html#module-curses) lib.

similar to this :

```
import curses

if __name__ == '__main__':
    stdscr = curses.initscr()
    stdscr.nodelay(False)
    curses.echo()
    curses.nonl()

while True:
    stdscr.addstr('#')
    stdscr.refresh()
    command = stdscr.getstr()

    if not command:
        continue

    if command == b'xys':
        stdscr.addstr('Execute xys block and print result')

    elif command == b'qwe':
        stdscr.addstr('Execute qwe block and print result')

    # ...
```

But it return this :

```
#xys
Execute xys block and print result#
#qwe
Execute qwe block and print result#
#
#
#
```

(after the `Execute qwe block and print result#` line I pressed the `enter` key)

The `stdscr.getstr()` function only wait for input half the time. The other half `command = ''` without any input. This is why you see the double `#` sign or the `#` sign at the end of each output.

The expecting result should be :

```
#xys
Execute xys block and print result
#qwe
Execute qwe block and print result
#
```

Any recommendation ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using the pyCharm terminal (with the `run` > `edit configurations...` > `emulate terminal in output console` checked) but apparently curses lib and pyCharm are not compatible.

When running the script in the normal terminal, it worked perfectly.

Hope this will help someone!